# Android - Broadcast not working after reboot

Tags: android, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver, reboot, bootcompleted

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and

```
<receiver android:name=".alarm.AlarmBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

AlarmBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Boot...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

In build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    multiDexEnabled true
```

The app works fine on the simulator, but on the device the broadcast does not start after restart.

Tested simulators: Pixel with API 29, 30 and 31

Tested devices: Honor with Android 9, Samsung with Android 10.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts):

> Apps that target Android 8.0 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.

You'd need to do one of the following:

> - Create the receiver at runtime by calling Context.registerReceiver(), instead of declaring the receiver in the manifest.
> - Use a scheduled job to check for the condition that would have triggered the implicit broadcast.